# How do I resolve a substring not found error?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, substring

I'm currently following Replit's 100 days of code tutorial. I am on day 40 and got tasked with making a dictionary to store the user's information, like their name.

My code:

```
info = {"name":"", "date of birth": "", "telephone number": "", "email": "", "address": ""}
questions = ["What is your name? ", "When were you born? ", "What is your telephone number? ", "What is your email? ", "What is your address? (Don't say it if you don't want to) "]
items = ["name", "date of birth", "telephone number", "email", "address"]

for i in questions:
  item = input(i)
  info[item.index(i)] = item #this was the line that caused the error.
```

(I took an approach of using loops)
But I run it and put in my answer. It then responds with a substring not found. I'd never heard of this before and didn't know what to do.

The error, word for word:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    info[item.index(i)] = item
ValueError: substring not found
```

I'm a little unsure about the `.index()` command, is it that?

Comment: `item` is the answer the user typed.  `i` is the question text.  Why are you expecting the question text to be present inside the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong variable. `item` is your answer, `items` is the list of keywords. Also the human readable question will not be in the `items` list. This should work:

```
for i, question in enumerate(questions):
    item = input(question)
    info[items[i]] = item
```

As a side note, this bug would have been easier to spot if you named your variables more sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable if you are confused of using for-loop
your can use while-loop instead

```
    # initilizing index as zero since index starts from zero
    index=0
    while True:
      item=input(questions[index])
      items[index]=item
      index+=1
      # if index is equal to length of the list then this loop should end
      if index==len(questions):
          break
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: which part of my solution needs improvement code or explanation please let me know to improve my solution next time

Comment: Yes, I found that out!